# Formal proof in choosing between two competing assertions regarding fraudulent/honest claims?

Tags: logic, argumentation

Please provide formal proof (or near enough, according to ability) for your decision as to which of the following two assertions is correct:

1. "Even if a claim is arrived at fraudulently, that does not mean the claim is untrue."
2. "A claim that is true, cannot be arrived at fraudulently."

A simple example of where the choice between these two assertions may come into play:

Someone publishes a claim that the Earth is flat. The claim is arrived at fraudulently, with empirical falsehoods and illogical reasoning. If we believe in the first assertion, we may consider the Earth to be flat, regardless. If we believe in the second assertion, the Earth cannot be flat.

EDIT:

To clarify, the idea of a "claim arrived at fraudulently" is that the claim is arrived at by empirical falsehoods, illogical reasoning is not enough, as any truth may be placed in an illogical sentence.

Comment: What have you tried? No idea?

Comment: A formal proof of what? They are empirical claims...

Comment: If you formalize them, you will discover that the two are mutually contradictory; this is all you can have "formally".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Maybe "formal proof" isn't the right phrase to use. Perhaps "rigorous proof" or "logical proof" would better describe my aim with the question. I want to see if it is possible to prove which of the two assertions is correct. I have a hunch that the second is correct, but have no idea how to prove that. If someone could prove that the first one is correct, I would be most interested. Please note the edit to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I say:

> I was a member of Shackleton's expedition on the Endurance so I can tell you from firsthand experience that Harry McNish was the carpenter on that expedition.

The claim is that Harry McNish was the carpenter on the Endurance.  This is factually true.  However, my justification for this claim was fraudulent, because I was not a member of that expedition and have no firsthand experience of it.